# WCF службу не видят извне

Tags: c#, .net, windows, веб-программирование, wcf

Хочу сделать так, что бы WCF служба была доступна извне.

При тестировании я использовал http://localhost:8080 и net.tcp://localhost:9100

Теперь я хочу протестировать работу службы с другого ПК и я поменял localhost на свой ip 10.2.16.22.

С другого ПК этот IP пингуется, но ,например, ссылка http://10.2.16.22:8080 не открывается.(С моего все хорошо).

Подскажите, что я мог упустить.

Comment: "я поменял localhost на свой ip 10.2.16.22" - где поменял? Роутер есть? Порт проброшен на машину с сервисом?

Comment: Откройте порты на файрволе: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="In_8080" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8080`, 
`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="In_9100" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9100`

Comment: @kmv, это нужно сделать на своей машине, на которой я запускаю службу?

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, эти команды разрешают входящие соединения на порты 8080 и 9100

Comment: @kmv наверное, ваш комментарий стоит сделать ответом

Comment: @kmv, благодарю, работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо на машине с WCF-сервисом разрешить входящие соединения на порты 8080 и 9100, используя либо оснастку `wf.msc`, либо выполнив команды:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="In_8080" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8080
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="In_9100" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9100
```