# Как запустить серверную программу с возможность обращения с удаленных компьютеров?

Tags: c#, .net, сервер

Всем доброго времени суток. Не так давно начал изучать сетевое программирование и на днях написал чат на tcp протоколе, состоящий из клиента и сервера. Проверял данную программу только на своем компьютере (с использованием локального ip), после того как я протестировал программу появилось желание подключить клиента не с того же компьютера, где запущен сервер, а с удаленного. Порывшись в гугле нашел какую-то инфу про проброс портов, что мне не помогло.
В общем меня интересует каким образом можно на своем компьютере запустить сервер так, чтобы клиенты могли подключаться к нему с удаленных компьютеров. Также интересно знать, есть ли сервисы предоставляющие такую услугу, чтобы можно было арендовать хостинг и на нем запустить мою программу (как с сайтами, с единственным отличием, что у меня экзешник)?
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь, информацию, литературу.

Comment: Может это поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516841/wcf-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5

Comment: Такой сервис называется VPS или VDS, предоставляется много кем. Только вам желательно делать кроссплатформенную программу, чтобы ее можно было запустить под Mono или CoreCLR. Потому что VDS-ки под линуксом стоят дешевле.

Answer (score -1):

Для организации такого рода сервиса дома необходимы следующие условия.

1. Статический IP адрес
2. Проброс порта за Nat (настройка маршрутизатора)
3. Настройка файрвола на маршрутизаторе и домашнем компьютере.

Настройка инфраструктуры очень похожа на настройку сайта на домашнем хостинге. 
Сервисов с такими услугами множество. Это может быть как выделенный сервер, так и виртуальный. Это может быть веб служба например на Microsoft Azure. Вариантов масса. Для развлечения подойдет домашний сервер, для серьезного проекта оптимальным будет использование WEB API.